# Remove unwanted padding at start of Row

Tags: flutter

the `Row` in my container contains padding on the left(I think). I want to align with the other children in the `Column`. I've been playing around with padding for the last two hours and find out how to eliminate the padding...

The sign in should align vertically from the left with buttons above it

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/img/signin.png'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
              child: Opacity(
                opacity: _showProgressIndicator ? 1 : 0,
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
//                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 180,
                padding:
                EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 60),
                child: Form(
                  key: formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.up,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            new FlatButton(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,

                              child: new Text('SIGN IN',
                                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context, SignInPage(widget.onSignedIn));
                              },

                            ),
                            Opacity(
                                opacity: _showMessage ? 1 : 0,
                                child: Text('CONSIDER GOOGLE', style:Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1)),
                            new FlatButton(
                              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                              child: new Text(
                                'SIGN UP WITH EMAIL',
                                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context, SignUpPage(widget.onSignedIn));
                              },
                            ),
                          ]),
                      new Container(
                        // padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: new Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new RaisedButton(
                              color: Colors.blue[800],
                             padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4))),
                              child: new Text('CONNECT WITH FACEBOOK',
                                  style: new TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      letterSpacing: 0.5,
                                      color: Colors.white)),
                              onPressed: loginWithFb,
                            ),
                            new SizedBox(height: 20),
                            new RaisedButton(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4))),
                              child: new Text('CONNECT WITH GOOGLE',
                                  style: new TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      letterSpacing: 0.5,
                                      color: Colors.white)),
                              onPressed: loginWithGoogle,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: I think what you mean is the default size of a FlatButton(), the ButtonTheme provides a button with minWidth: 88.0, height: 36.0 as mentioned in [ButtonTheme class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ButtonTheme-class.html), this means that the SIGN IN button has a minWidth of 88.0. so it looks like it has a padding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could fix this by changing the default [`ButtonTheme`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ButtonTheme-class.html) if I understand correctly what you mean, because you said:

> The sign in should align vertically from the left with buttons above it

Don't you mean horizontally from the left, if that is the case try this:

Wrap the `Flatbutton` in a Theme with `ThemeData` and a new `ButtonTheme`, then change the padding and minWidth with your own(when I only changed the padding or width it didn't work).
This removes the default from the ButtonTheme
**Example:**

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Theme(
        data: ThemeData(buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(minWidth: 20.0,padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0))),
        child: new FlatButton(
          child: new Text('SIGN IN',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1),
          onPressed: () {
          },

        ),
      ),
      Opacity(
          opacity: true ? 1 : 0,
          child: Text('CONSIDER GOOGLE', style:Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1)),
      new FlatButton(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        child: new Text(
          "SIGN UP WITH EMAIL ",
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
        ),
        onPressed: () {

        },
      ),
    ]),
```

**Result:**

[image: Buttons]